# Pass a jquery variable to @Url.Action MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

How can I pass my client side variable to controller using Url.Action.

I am trying to do like this, but it's not working

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("printtopdf","batch",new {allocationId=unSelected}))';
```

In the above line 'unSelected' is a client side variable and comma separated values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work for you. I find it a bit more cleaner and is an alternative option.

```
window.location = "/batch/printtopdf?allocationId=" + unSelected;
```

It stands for

```
window.location = "/yourControllerName/yourActionMethodName?QueryStringId=" + yourVariable;
```

Comment: unSelected is an comma seperated values. Shall we able to send it as you mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

`@Url.Action` creates the link on the server, but `unSelected` only exists on the client. What you would need to do is append the unSelected querystring to the generated link.

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("printtopdf","batch",new {}))' + '?allocationId=' + unSelected;
```

**Edit:**

The way I'm creating the link assumes that the link will not have any other queryString parameter, otherwise, you'll need to conver the '?' to '&'